# How to change the woocommerce email template width?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am trying to increase the email template width. And I am trying to modify the `email-style.php`, but it seems no way to change. How can I change it?

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The most useful one to copy is `emails/email-styles.php` and there you'll find the width is defined in two places at 600px; `#template-container` and `#template-body` but there's also all the other styles. Anything that is not defined but exists in the email can be added to this file.

I use an email preview plugin so I can see the effect in a web inspector.

if you wanted to be really clever you could include an external css file and then use scss to integrate with the rest of your site styles - eg colours.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most common approach to do is to create a folder in your theme called woocommerce/ and then copy the entire templates/ directory from your woocommerce plugin or [github](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/email-styles.php) into that. This will override the functionality from the plugin.

Here you can find the hardcoded table width.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to do this is by adding some custom styles to the woocommerce_email_header. You can add the following code to your theme's `functions.php` file to do this:

```
// Change width of WooCommerce e-mail templates to 800px, and make the layout responsive
add_filter('woocommerce_email_header', function () {
    echo '
        <style type="text/css">
            #template_body,
            #template_container,
            #template_footer {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 800px;
            }
        </style>
    ';
});
```